# Low grade on matrix problem in C even if I did it right?

Tags: c, matrix

Freshman studying computer science here, had this problem:

> "Assume there is a matrix of dimensions mxn, representing the value of telephone calls of m subscribers in a period of n months. Write a C program which determines the months in which the telephone company registered the same value for all subscribers. The data transfer will be done exclusively through parameters."

This is what I tried and got graded a 5/10 on it. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the code or provide a better solution?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[3][3],i,j,k,n,m,vectorfound[100],p,foundmonth;
    printf("Number of months: ");scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Number of customers: ");scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf("a[%d][%d]= ",i,j);scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("You have chosen the matrix: "); printf ("\n");
    
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        printf("%d ",a[i][j]); printf("\n");
    }

    
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        p=0; foundmonth=1; k=a[i][0];               
        for(j=1;j<n;j++)
        if (a[i][j]!=k) foundmonth=0;
        if (foundmonth)                                     // only executes if a month has been found
        {
            printf("The months in which the company has recorded the same value for all of the customers are: ");
            vectorfound[p]=i; // vector which saves the months with the constant value
            printf("%d ",vectorfound[p]);
            p++; 
        } 
    }
    
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Probably belongs on Codereview exchange.

Comment: Few problems, mainly that your array is a fixed size `int[3][3]`, thus you don't truly support a dynamic number of customers or months. I assume you should be using dynamic memory to allocate an appropriate number of bytes. Also as a freshman, note a matrix of dimensions `m` by `n` can be represented by a two-dimensional array of size `int[m][n]`. But dynamically constructing this in C is slightly different from some languages you may have seen before.

Comment: "The data transfer will be done exclusively through parameters."

Comment: *Who* game you a bad grade? Your teacher? Some web-site? If your teacher, why don't you ask him or her?

Comment: Since I don't know the grading criteria, I don't know if this is a problem, but your code (m=months, n=subscribers) doesn't match the description (m=subscribers, n=months).

Comment: Don't put multiple statements on the same line.  It's way easier to debug and read if you use line breaks everywhere.

Comment: You can break out of your `for(j=1;j<n;j++)` loop as soon as you find a record that doesn't match. e.g. `for(j=1;j<n&&foundmonth;j++)`. (Obviously doesn't matter for a 3x3 matrix, but for one of serious size it might.)

Comment: The indentation is terrible.  `void main()` is wrong.  `<conio.h>` is nonstandard and isn't (or shouldn't) be necessary.

Comment: Another thing - you don't technically need a 2-d matrix array. Or any array. While you are in your inner for-loop reading values, you just need to check if the value read in is the same as the previous value  But I suspect the homework was to teach multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

First statements in `main`

```
int a[3][3],i,j,k,n,m,vectorfound[100],p,foundmonth;
printf("Number of months: ");scanf("%d",&m);
printf("Number of customers: ");scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf("a[%d][%d]= ",i,j);scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
```

The moment `m` or `n` is greater than `3`, you are in undefined behavior territory with a strong likelihood of crashing.  Your `a` array isn't big enough to hold anything bigger than a 3x3.

Also, your `printf` statement inside the for-lopp is preceding the `scanf` statement. Whatever gets printed is likely garbage data off the stack.